# Hotmail and Facebook accounts have been hacked

Tags: facebook, outlook.com

Both my Hotmail and Facebook accounts have been hacked and I am not able to access them. My email account has important information and data.

How do I retrieve my accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the "I forgot my password" link at the login screen of the sites? Maybe you could recover the password if you remember the answer to your security question.

Also do not use the same password on different sites. If malicious hackers find out the password to one of your sites they will try to log in with the same password on other sites. My advice is to use a password manager like [LastPass](http://lastpass.com/) to generate and store different random password for each site you use and protect them with one strong master password.

Also from now on be careful when login in to your account from a system owned by someone else, or a public computer. Also have an Anti-Virus Suite installed in your system and scan your computer regularly. As far as I know, if your account is hacked and the hacked is adamant on not letting you get it back, there is nothing much you can do.

Comment: this is great , but how to recover my accounts on hotmail and facebook.

Comment: If somebody hacked your mail and changed your password then your only hope to regain control over your account is to reset your password. This can be done in Hotmail by clicking on the link "Forgot your password?" on the login screen just below the password field and following the instructions there. The same goes for Facebook.